# Replacing column names

Tags: r

I have created a smaller table from a larger table. The columns selected in this smaller table are not fixed i.e. the user can select a different set in the future.

The column names in both the tables are based on sap definitions

I have another file which maps all the column names to simpler format.

If the list was fixed, I could have used the rename option. Since, the list of columns are not fixed, the rename option is tedious.

How do i ensure, that user gets the right names, irrespective of his selection?

Larger table A=

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
8,9,10,11,12,13,14
```

smaller table B =

```
a,b,c
1,2,3
8,9,10
```

Table with name mapping C=

```
Col1,Col2
a,name
b,age
c,height
d,weight
e,salary
f,firm
g,address
```

I want my program to refer to the mapping table C & rename the column names in B. The expected output in this case -

```
name,age,height
1,2,3
8,9,10
```

If in the future, the user select columns b, f & g. The code should be able to replace it with the right names using the mapping file. I hope its clear

Comment: added an example to the original text

Comment: You can use `dput` to share the data so they we know exactly what kind of data it is.

Comment: No need to comment what you've added or deleted. This is clear through the editing history. You could try `car::recode`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `match` (assuming that the columns of mapping dataset ('df3') are `character` class

```
names(df2) <- df3$Col2[match(names(df2), df3$Col1)]
df2
#     name age height
#1    1   2      3
#2    8   9     10
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(a = c(1L, 8L), b = c(2L, 9L), c = c(3L, 10L), 
d = c(4L, 11L), e = c(5L, 12L), f = c(6L, 13L), g = c(7L, 
14L)), .Names = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -2L))

df2 <- structure(list(name = c(1L, 8L), age = c(2L, 9L), 
 height = c(3L,    
 10L)), .Names = c("name", "age", "height"), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c(NA, -2L))

df3 <- structure(list(Col1 = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"), 
  Col2 = c("name", 
 "age", "height", "weight", "salary", "firm", "address")), 
 .Names = c("Col1", "Col2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
  -7L))
```

Comment: I tried the above option. the columns of the mapping data set are character class.
The headers/names of the columns disappear after using the above code

Comment: @NimishVaddiparti  You may need to check the `str` of your dataset as it is working fine for me

Comment: I checked the str of the dataset. The following is the resultant output, post the check

data.frame': 437295 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ MBLNR     : chr  "4903148784" "4903148784" "4903150748" "4903150748" ...
 $ MATNR     : chr  "GALCW" "GALCW" "GALCW" "GALCW" ...
 $ MENGE     : num  10.85 11.33 5.72 5.71 5.75 ...
 $ BUDAT_MKPF: chr  "20101008" "20101008" "20101008" "20101008" ...
 $ BWART     : chr  "101" "101" "101" "101" ...

Comment: the str output of the mapping data set

'data.frame': 198 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Header1: chr  "MANDT" "MBLNR" "MJAHR" "ZEILE" ...
 $ Header2: chr  "Cl." "Mat. Doc." "MatYr" "Item" ...